# Drop shadow extends beyond the artboard and causes the picture dimensions to change

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

I have a drop shadow on a small image. The drop shadow extends beyond the arboard's boundary. This causes the 120x150 image to turn into a 132x150 image because it tries to include the drop shadow in the image as well. Is there a way to force it to only export the artboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the "Save for Web" option there is a checkbox "clip to artboard"
that will do it.

Or if you are saving as a vector, eps or svg as an option to "use artboard"